# Creating xml documents using ocaml

Tags: xml, functional-programming, ocaml

I am looking forward for ways to create xml documents using ocaml. Any libraries with examples will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library [Xmlm](http://erratique.ch/software/xmlm/doc/Xmlm) is pretty easy to use and straightforward.